# Incorrect key file for table error. If limited disc space is culprit, how can I modify query code so less space is consumed in MySQL tmpdir folder?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temporary-files

I am using MySQL with Sequel Pro on a Mac Pro OSX Mavericks and am trying to run the code for a stored procedure in order to add two new columns to a table. The procedure does math operations on columns from two different tables, one of which is the same table as the destination/output table 'starting_pitcher_stats'.

I keep getting the following error when I call the procedure:

Incorrect key file for table '/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n000009800002_/T/#sql43_1_82.MYI'; try to repair it

Here is the code for the stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS starting_pitcher_std_wRC;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE starting_pitcher_std_wRC()
BEGIN
    DECLARE pit_id CHAR(10);
    DECLARE gdate DATE;
    DECLARE seq INT;
    DECLARE YEARID INT;
    DECLARE wOBAsc VARCHAR (255);
    DECLARE stdwOBA DOUBLE;
    DECLARE wOBAgame DOUBLE;
    DECLARE BFP DOUBLE;
    DECLARE stdBFP DOUBLE;
    DECLARE lgwOBAgame DOUBLE;
    DECLARE lgstdwOBA DOUBLE;
    DECLARE lgRoverPAg DOUBLE;
    DECLARE stdlgRoverPA DOUBLE;
    DECLARE stdwRC DOUBLE;
    DECLARE wRCg DOUBLE;
    DECLARE prev_year YEAR(4);
    DECLARE end_of_cursor BOOLEAN;

    DECLARE no_table CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '42S02';

    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
      SELECT s.Starting_Pitcher, s.Game_Date, s.Game_Number, s.YEAR_ID, s.wOBAScale, s.std_wOBA, s.wOBA_game, s.BFPorPA, s.std_BFP, l.lg_wOBA_game, l.lg_std_wOBA, l.lg_RoverPA_g, l.std_lg_RoverPA, s.std_wRC, s.wRC_g  
        FROM starting_pitcher_stats AS s, lg_starting_pitcher_game_log AS l
       ORDER BY s.Starting_Pitcher, s.Game_Date, s.Game_Number;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
      SET end_of_cursor := TRUE;

    SET end_of_cursor := FALSE;  -- reset
    SET prev_year := 0;          -- reset control-break

    OPEN c1;

    fetch_loop: LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO pit_id, gdate, seq, YEARID, wOBAsc, stdwOBA, wOBAgame, BFP, stdBFP, lgwOBAgame, lgstdwOBA, lgRoverPAg, stdlgRoverPA, wRCg, stdwRC;
      IF end_of_cursor THEN
        LEAVE fetch_loop;
      END IF;

      -- check control-break conditions
      IF YEAR(gdate) != prev_year THEN
        SET stdwRC := 0;
        SET wRCg := 0;
        SET prev_year := YEAR(gdate);
      END IF;

        SET wRCg := (((wOBAgame-lgwOBAgame)/wOBASc)+(lgRoverPAg))*BFPgame;
        SET stdwRC := (((stdwOBA-lgstdwOBA)/wOBASc)+(stdlgRoverPA))*stdBFP;

      UPDATE starting_pitcher_stats
        SET s.std_wRC =stdwRC,
        s.wRC_g =wRCg
          WHERE s.YEAR_ID=YEARID
          AND s.Game_date=gdate
          AND s.Game_Number=seq
          AND s.Starting_Pitcher = pit_id;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;
  END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Following the error I get all Null values in the two new columns 'std_wrc' and 'wrc_g' I am trying to create.

Here is a screen shot of the table structure of the destination table of the stored procedure I'm trying to call:

[image: screenshot of table structure of starting_pitcher_stats, the destination table for query and source of some of column data used to perform math operations]

when I run df -h to determine size and disk space used in the entire mounted file systems, this is the result:

```
    Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk2s2   298Gi  185Gi  113Gi    63% 48450408  29608418   62%   /
devfs          187Ki  187Ki    0Bi   100%      646         0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s2   931Gi  271Gi  660Gi    30% 71005440 173101226   29%   /Volumes/DATASTORE_Z
/dev/disk0s2   149Gi  288Mi  148Gi     1%    73803  38914943    0%   /Volumes/Disk_smaller                       
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0         0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0         0  100%   /home
```

All 113G of available space is used up in / directory on partition /dev/disk2s2 during the process of running the query.  With with about 2G left of space I get the following message:

```
Terminal has detected that the system is running low on swap space. Scrollback buffers may automatically be trimmed to conserve memory
```

Can someone please help with optimizing this query to avoid space problems? If you need more information, please let me know so I can provide it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let's migrate this to the dba site.

Comment: Ok thanks Drew. How can we do that?

Comment: Best for you to create a new question [on dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql) then delete it here.

Comment: ok, I posted it to dba site.  Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question here seeking assistance with modifying query itself as a way to minimize space consumption.